# Querying a specific array element in ElasticSearch

Tags: .net, linq, elasticsearch, nest, opensearch

I have some indexed documents which have a field which is associated with a vector of floats. I'd like to check if the last value of this vector is `0`.

```json
// Example
{
    "VectorField": [1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 0]
}
```

I tried to use Linq to create the query but cannot find how to make it work.

```
descriptor.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.VectorField!.Last()).Value(0));
```

Is there a way to query the value of a float array element in ElasticSearch? Maybe using `script`?

Comment: Use `script` or split your vector (if it's not too long) into a set of fields `vector_0`, `vector_1`, etc.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with Linq but make sure you use `match` query and not `term`.

Comment: I'm gonna try, thanks!